Which CUDA subpackage contains nv_decode.h?
(Automated) CUDA instllation on Windows involves several subpackages.
Which of these is supposed to contain nv_decode.h?
Note: Not a header of the NVDEC library for video decoding; this one lets us demangle names in CUDA-compiled objects.
